# React Navigation Header Props not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm having a problem when passing props to the header. The  component in each of the stacks takes the value declared in the first stack "(Home)".
I have a switch in the component that has to render different things in each of the views. For some reason when doing console.log inside the header in the different views, it always throws me the value of the "Home view".

```
  <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" >
  {/* <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth"> */}
    {/* Auth Navigator: Include Login and Signup */}
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Auth"
      component={CryptoAuth}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    {/* Navigation Drawer as a landing page */}
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
      // Hiding header for Navigation Drawer
      options={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header prop={"Home"}/> ,headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, elevation: 0} }}
      // options={({ route }) => ({
      //   headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
      // })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="CollectionDetails"
      component={CollectionDetails}
      options={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header prop={"CollectionDetails"}/>, headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, elevation: 0}}}
    />
       <Stack.Screen
      name="NFTDetails"
      component={NFTDetails}
      options={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header prop={"NFTDetails"}/>, headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, elevation: 0}}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={Profile}
      options={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header prop={"Profile"}/>, headerTitleAlign: 'center', headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, elevation: 0}}}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The options should define as a function.

```
options={props => ({
   title: $t('back'),
   headerBackTestID: 'BackButton',
   headerTitle: () => <HomeHeader {...props} />,
   headerRight: () => <RightHeader {...props} />,
})}
```